# System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal Error when uploading file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to upload a video to Windows Azure Media Services. Using the example that Microsoft gave I am getting an error saying `System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal`. However when I change this line from `var uploadFilePath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);` to `var uploadFilePath = Path.GetFileName(@"c:\video\ocean.mp4");`. The file uploads and it works fine.

```
<code>
        try
        {
            var uploadFilePath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            var context = new CloudMediaContext("123media", "###############");
            var uploadAsset = context.Assets.Create(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uploadFilePath), AssetCreationOptions.None);
            var assetFile = uploadAsset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath));
            assetFile.Upload(uploadFilePath);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = ex.Data.ToString();
        }

 <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
<div>    
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" CssClass="btn-button" runat="server" Width="325px" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</div>
</form>
```

`at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.Upload(String path) at WIT.test3.UploadButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WIT\WIT\test3.aspx.cs:line 37`

Comment: can you also post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sick... [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [HttpPostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpPostedFile(v=vs.110).aspx) (of which type is the [PostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload(v=vs.110).aspx) control) is actually the Fully Qualified Name of the file **on the client**, **not** on the server.

You have to actually first [save the uploadedfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) locally, with same name, then pass it to the AssetFile object for upload.

Some try to fix the code:

```
    try
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        var serverFileName = Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(serverFileName);
        var context = new CloudMediaContext("123media", "###############");
        var uploadAsset = context.Assets.Create(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), AssetCreationOptions.None);
        var assetFile = uploadAsset.AssetFiles.Create(fileName);
        assetFile.Upload(serverFileName);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = ex.Data.ToString();
    }
```

Can you quote where did you get this sample code from? BTW, you can get [my Sample MVC based project](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb). I updated it about 3 months ago, so must be working.

Comment: Yes log into Azure Portal and add Media Services. They give you examples on how to upload, encode, deliver and stream a video. I just copied the example.

Comment: It works. Thank you for your assistance and the link. I am not that familiar yet with MVC but it is a good reference.

Comment: Actually all the samples provided on this page you refer (after you create a Media Service and check the tutorial) - all refer to a console application, and not a web application. It seems that you have tried to make console app code work in a Web App, hence the problems you encounter. This is not issue with documentation.